# Should Linux resolver fail back to primary DNS server when it's available?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

Maybe this is a dumb question but should Linux DNS resolver prefer primary DNS server over secondary and primary or is it free to use any of them?
I have a pretty standard ubuntu 20.04 LTS image with resolver configuration as per [Microsoft recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances?tabs=ubuntu)

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
options timeout:1 attempts:5
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search reddog.microsoft.com
```

And I'm quite often in a situation where secondary or tertiary DNS server is used when primary is available

```
$ systemd-resolve --status |tail -5
  Current DNS Server: Z.Z.Z.Z
         DNS Servers: X.X.X.X
                      Y.Y.Y.Y
                      Z.Z.Z.Z
          DNS Domain: reddog.microsoft.com
```

Is that expected?
Shouldn't resolver prefer primary DNS server if it's available?
Any point to resolver documentation would be welcome.
Or maybe this is not even a matter of specific resolver but part of RFC requirement.

Comment: Technically, you have only one DNS 127.0.0.53 configured, and options in your resolv.conf are related to that server. Then you have your systemd resolver which has more DNS servers configured. I am not familiar how systemd-resolved works, but such programs usually perform DNS caching. Therefore, I am not sure options from resolv.conf are used in systemd-resolved.

Comment: With the current default Ubuntu configuration /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to /run/systemd/resolve.conf.  So it's kind of obvious I asked about the respecting DNS order by systemd-resolve which is a default solution for Ubuntu (maybe other distros too). And it looks like it doesn't care about the order. Formally probably it doesn't have to although Windows prefers first server on the list and Linux prior to systemd-resolved used to follow the order too (unless option rotate was used). So this is a big change in the Linux (and probably the whole IT) world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typical behavior of a DNS resolver that with multiple DNS servers defined, the servers are used round-robin. There is no concept of "primary" or "secondary" server in the resolver configuration - each of the configured servers is treated as equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, any piece of documentation (RFC or linux resolver doc) to support that statement would be great. Is this true for other OSes (such as Microsoft Windows) as well?

Comment: I think there is a practice and there is a theory. When it comes to the theory I think you might be right - there is no concept of primary and secondary server. When it comes to practice windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd197552(v=ws.10) will prefer first server on the list but secondary won't be preferred over tertiary.Linux with traditional /etc/resolv.conf also seems to respect the order but system-resolve does round robin. Would be great to know how to tell systemd-resolve how to follow the order for DHCP nameservers

Comment: Documentation: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/29608/files

Comment: feature request: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/29614